# (GKE Dataproc) Global region is not supported for Dataproc Virtual Cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, dataproc

I am trying to create Dataproc cluster on GKE. I was following steps on the [GCP official website.](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/dpgke/quickstarts/dataproc-gke-quickstart-create-cluster#dataproc-gke-cluster-create-gcloud)

After running the following command on gcloud CLI,

```
DP_CLUSTER="test-gke" \
  REGION="asia-east2-a" \
  GKE_CLUSTER="airflow-cluster" \
  GKE_CLUSTER_NAMESPACE="spark" \
  BUCKET="test-spark" \
  DP_POOLNAME="dataproc-pool"

gcloud dataproc clusters gke create $DP_CLUSTER \
    --region=$REGION \
    --gke-cluster=$GKE_CLUSTER \
    --spark-engine-version=latest \
    --staging-bucket=$BUCKET \
    --pools="name=$POOL_NAME,roles=default" \
    --setup-workload-identity
```

I have encountered the error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.dataproc.clusters.gke.create) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Multiple validation errors:
 - GKE location 'asia-east2-a' is not supported by this Dataproc region.
 - Global region is not supported for Dataproc Virtual Cluster.
```

On its official website, it says Dataproc is available across all regions and zones of the GCP.[image]

Is there any way to solve this error?
Any comments would be appreciated.

Comment: could you try `REGION="asia-east2"`?

Comment: Agree - I think the error might be misleading.  `asia-east2-a` is a zone.  `asia-east2` is the region

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Dataproc does support all regions and zones. However, in your case while specifying the environment variable `region` you are assigning it to a `zone` ie. `asia-east2-a`. Specifying the REGION as `asia-east2` should solve your error.